# Codeigniter 4 работа с категориями

Tags: php, codeigniter

нужно при формировании страницы вывести вместо id категории название, в таблице с новостью категории хранятся по id
вот код вывода на странице

```
<? foreach ($pages as $item): ?>
<tbody>
<tr type="input">
<th scope="row" class="hidden-xs"><?= $item['id'] ?></th>
<td class="hidden-xs"><a href="edit/news/<?= $item['id'] ?>-<?= $item['alt_title'] ?>.html"><?= $item['title'] ?>
</td>
<td class="hidden-xs">
<?= $item['category'] ?> - вот здесь вместо id нужно название из таблицы с категориями
</td>
<td class="hidden-xs"><?= $item['create_at'] ?></td>
<td class="hidden-xs">
<a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success shadow" href="edit/news/<?= $item['id'] ?>-<?= $item['alt_title'] ?>.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger shadow" href="delete/news/<?= $item['id'] ?>-<?= $item['alt_title'] ?>.html">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</td>
<td class="hidden-xs">
<div class="checkbox"><input name="g1" value="1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, пока сделал такой костыль

```
<? $cat = explode(', ', $item['category']) ?>
    <? foreach ($cat as $items): ?>
        <? foreach ($category as $iteme): ?>
            <? if ($items == $iteme['id']): ?>
               <?= $iteme['name'] ?><br>
            <? endif; ?>
        <? endforeach; ?>
    <? endforeach; ?>
```